# couldn't get Bootstrap carousel to work with Ember

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, carousel

trying to understand why its not working.

I have something like this.

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="new-prospect-container">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
   {{#each model}}
      <div class="item">
      ...
     </div>
   {{/each}}
   </div>
</div>
```

But Botostrap's first class api means that we don't need to execute any JS methods and their widgets will work automatically. The problem is I suspect Bootstrap would have executed this prior to my {{model}} being filled up by an Ajax requests. So this Carousel won't work.

What's annoying is i already tried turning off their data-api - $(document).off('.data-api'); and manually call their carousel method - still won't work.

The carousel works with hard coded data - but once I try to populate the carousel div items from my Ember model, it just stops working.

1. Any idea?
2. Why does this exist - https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap ? does it exist to exactly solve my issue here? (although there's no carousel)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 - I hope that [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/U6V2x/) solve your problem.

```
App.CarouselView = Ember.View.extend({    
    templateName: 'carousel',
    classNames: ['carousel', 'slide'],
    init: function() { 
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        // disable the data api from boostrap
        $(document).off('.data-api');      
        // at least one item must have the active class, so we set the first here, and the class will be added by class binding
        var obj = this.get('content.firstObject');
        Ember.set(obj, 'isActive', true);
    },
    previousSlide: function() {
        this.$().carousel('prev');
    },
    nextSlide: function() {
        this.$().carousel('next');
    },
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().carousel();
    },
    indicatorsView: Ember.CollectionView.extend({
        tagName: 'ol',
        classNames: ['carousel-indicators'],        
        contentBinding: 'parentView.content',
        itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
            click: function() {
                var $elem = this.get("parentView.parentView").$();
                $elem.carousel(this.get("contentIndex"));
            },
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(''),
            classNameBindings: ['content.isActive:active']            
        })
    }),
    itemsView: Ember.CollectionView.extend({        
        classNames: ['carousel-inner'],
        contentBinding: 'parentView.content',
        itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
            classNames: ['item'],
            classNameBindings: ['content.isActive:active'],
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('\
                <img {{bindAttr src="view.content.image"}} alt=""/>\
                <div class="carousel-caption">\
                    <h4>{{view.content.title}}</h4>\
                    <p>{{view.content.content}}</p>\
                </div>')
        })
    })
});
```

2 - I don't know why the carousel isn't include in ember-boostrap.

Comment: wow thanks so much for this effort! does it really have to be implemented this way? sorry i'm still new to Ember and this whole MVC javascript framework.

Comment: I think so. The only hack that I have done is the isActive, setted in the first element, but if its bore you, you can use a _isActive etc. To not conflict with some data of your models.

Comment: hi Marcio, your code works perfectly on my app. I wanted to ask you this as i ran out of idea. But each content box in my carousel needs to have 3 items. My idea is to populate the App.CarouselView.itemsView  every 3 items, then inject it on the fly. Not sure if that's possible or how its done. Would you have any other idea?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question maybe because english isn't my native language. Do you want to have a diferent view for each item in carousel?

Comment: Maybe a different view in each item would help. This is a perfect example of what i'm trying to achieve - http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html Set it to scroll 3 items per click. Now click on next / prev and see how it scrolls 3 items at a time? So basically on your itemsView i need to plug/iterate 3 items from App.carouselData at a time.

Comment: Sorry I think that isn't possible to show 3 slides, in twitter boostrap carousel. This is the reason that I used the jcarousel, some day in a project, without ember. But I think that integrate jcarousel with ember, could be more difficult because, it create some divs in the html :(.

Comment: Hi Marcio, thanks for your response. If you meant that 3 slides in twitter bootstrap is not possible, we have done that without Ember. Twitter's bootstrap doesn't care what you put inside each slide/item, you just need to set the width. Or did you rather mean that to wire 3 items per slide is not possible with Ember and Bootstrap's carousel?

Comment: @David, I have re-factored Marcio's excellent solution to wrap the carousel in a [Ember.Component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html) to be more compliant with how actions should be organized in Ember. Also, modified the bindAttr to bind-attr in the rendered child view. Please view the [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk955/2/) for details.

Comment: Hi I want to update the carousel data as my route changes.My template look like this {{view MyApp.CarouselView content=carouselData}}   ... and to rerender I am doing something like this inside carousel view ..   dataUpdated: function(){
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('content'), //tried 'view.content'         ..... and my route has .... actions:{
  updateCarousel :function(navigatedProduct){
   this.set('carouselData',navigatedProduct);
  }

Answer (score 4):

So I have a solution for this, but it's not for the squeamish.

Bootstrap isn't specific enough about what elements it looks for in the case of the Carousel. When the carousel function goes to inventory what elements it's to manipulate, it chokes on the metamorph tags that Ember injects into the DOM. Basically, when it goes to see how many images there are, it will always find 2 more than there actually are.

I made changes to the underlying code of the carousel in the bootstrap library, here's what I did.

```
Line 337, change:
this.$items  = this.$active.parent().children()
TO
this.$items  = this.$active.parent().children('.item')


Line 379, change:
var $next     = next || $active[type]()
TO
var $next     = next || $active[type]('.item')


Line 401, change:
var $nextIndicator = $(that.$indicators.children()[that.getActiveIndex()])
TO
var $nextIndicator = $(that.$indicators.children('li')[that.getActiveIndex()])
```

This helps the carousel plugin ignore the metamorph tags.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it by using the following method. Note that I'm using ember-cli but it's fairly easy to adapt.

This is the `templates/components/photo-carousel.hbs` file:

```
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        {{#each photo in photos}}
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to=""></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        {{#each photo in photos}}
            <div class="item">
                <img {{bind-attr src="photo.completeUrl" title="photo.caption" alt="photo.caption"}} />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    {{photo.caption}}
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>

    <!-- removed right and left controls for clarity -->
</div>
```

This is the `components/photo-carousel.js`:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {

        // Add the active classes (required by the carousel to work)
        Ember.$('.carousel-inner div.item').first().addClass('active');
        Ember.$('.carousel-indicators li').first().addClass('active');

        // Set the values of data-slide-to attributes
        Ember.$('.carousel-indicators li').each(function (index, li) {
            Ember.$(li).attr('data-slide-to', index);
        });

        // Start the carousel
        Ember.$('.carousel').carousel();
    }
});
```

Note that setting the `active` classes manually will not be required with future versions of Ember since the `each` helper will provide the `index` of the current item.