# bootstrap carousel not working, impacted by ember metamorph identifiers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

Here's a newbie question for you

my stack: mongodb, node, ember, bootstrap
i am using ember-tools to help with structuring

I have a bootstrap carousel that I am trying to dynamically populate from the database. The database is accessed through a restful API and loaded into the the front-end ember model in the route.

```
model: function() {
  return $.getJSON('/headliners');
}
```

the model follows the following schema:

```
{
    id:1, 
    active:true, 
    title:"This is a title", 
    description:"and a short description", 
    buttontext: "Learn More", 
    buttonurl: "http://www.blah.com", 
    imageurl:"/images/apicture.jpg"
}
```

if the active attribute is true, then the class should be "item active". if false, then the class should = "item". here is the template code that tries to make this happen

```
{{#each model}}

    {{#if active}}          
        <div class="item active">   
    {{else}}
        <div class="item">
    {{/if}}

    <img {{bindAttr src="imageurl"}} />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" {{bindAttr href="buttonurl"}}">{{buttontext}}</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

This template works as expected, but includes metamorph identifiers which are causing some problems. (if i remove the metamorph identifiers, the page renders correctly)

more specifically, the issue i am having is that the metamorph identifiers used to handle the (#if)(else) are impacting the carousel object.

I am pretty sure there is a common way to handle this situation- what is the best approach to modifying the class if the active attribute is true but removing the metamorph identifiers so the carousel view is not impacted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Márcio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1846480/marcio-rodrigues-correa-junior) has given a really good answer with an example showin bootstrap and the carousel

[couldn't get Bootstrap carousel to work with Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068993/couldnt-get-bootstrap-carousel-to-work-with-ember)

Concerning the metamorph tags, they exist for updating values etc.  They only exist on bound values, you can unbind values and the metamorph tags won't be injected around those values (see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound). This also means as the underlying values change the ui won't update.

Comment: thanks. i am playing with Marcio's solution. I am using ember-tools, which uses the handlebars runtime. In order to access the Ember.Handlebar.compile I needed the full handlebars release (specifically version 1.0). I downloaded the 1.0 version and then upgraded ember-tools.  I am still getting an error a typeerror in the Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) function, specifically at $next[0].offsetWidth.  I will continue to look at this and report back.

Comment: ok, i had a conflict with an attribute that had nothing to do with the carousel. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

@kingpin2k has the answer right away, but I just wanted to add, that - with Ember.js and Handlebars.js - you should **never** do something like

```
{{#if isTrue}}
<div class="some-class added-if-true">
{{else}}
<div class="some-class">
{{/if}}
```

<strike>but instead, working with **bind-attr**:</strike>

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":some-class isTrue:added-if-true"}}>
```

as explained and shown here: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/

Since Ember 2.0 you don't have to use `bind-attr` anymore but you can actually use inline helpers to manipulate the DOM Objects class list like this:

```
<div class="some-class {{if shouldAdd 'added-if-true' 'added-if-false'}}">
```